# Google Drive Android API - Sharing files in App folder?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to create an app that stores files "safely" from the user, and the App Folder in the Google Drive API seems perfect for this. But I also want people using the app to be able to share the app-specific files (and stay in sync) with each other.

So my question is: Is it possible to share any data that is located in the hidden "App folder" of Google Drive?

Comment: ever got an answer for that?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: found any soulution?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is interested in a solution:

I found no way to sync shared files with the google android native API. (besides the file picker) 
In case you want to do so you have to use the google drive rest API.
A little advantage for this solution. I think the java rest API is anyway much more suited for this kind of work. Code gets in that way much more readable.